# Theme specific drupal commerce product form

Tags: theming, forms, commerce

I want to create a .tpl file for each specific product type form. I get that I can create a custom product template and add this code on my theme's template.php:

```
'commerce_product_ui_product_form' => array(
               'arguments' => array(
                    'form' => NULL,
                    ),
               'template' => 'templates/products form/node--add--product', // set the path here if not in root theme directory
               'render element' => 'form',
            )
```

The problem is this changes all the product type's form. How can I find the Form ID for each specific product type form?

[image]

Comment: you can do it by using "node--add--yourtype"

Comment: Hi @Adi Thanks for the fast reply. I will try it, but what will be the code for my theme's template.php, because I noticed that the product type form has only the id="commerce_product_ui_product_form", what ID can I use for each specific product type? For example I have a product type Venue package what will be the ID?

Comment: you dsm in your template then you can find of your product form id

Comment: @Adi I tried the dsm and like I said, all the product type form has the same ID "commerce_product_ui_product_form", or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same form ID for every type, but you can find context in the form state, e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_form_commerce_product_ui_product_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $product = $form_state['commerce_product'];
  $product_type = commerce_product_type_load($product->type);

  if ($product_type->name == 'foo') {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Clive. But if I do it this way I won't be able to create a .tpl file since this is for a custom module. I was wondering if I can add it on my theme's template instead so that I can make my own custom .tpl file because I will be moving a lot of stuff around and adding custom views on the .tpl file.

Comment: Why not just call the theme function something else and `if ($product_type->name == 'foo') { $form['#theme'] = 'bar'; }`?

Comment: I get this error whenever I try out your code: "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in custom_module_form_commerce_product_ui_product_form_alter" I use this code `if ($product_type->name == 'caterer_package') {
 $form['#theme'] = 'templates/product/product-node-form'; 
 }`

Comment: Not sure what to tell you I'm afraid, that code is actually copied from the Commerce Product UI module's own code for the same form :/ [`commerce_product_product_form`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21commerce%21modules%21product%21includes%21commerce_product.forms.inc/function/commerce_product_product_form/8). If the code is working for them but not you, the problem is likely to be somewhere else