# Override commerce product form

Tags: 7, commerce

i'm trying to override some fields in commerce_products_ui form in my-module, i need to 'disable' or 'hide' some fields, this question is similar to [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194014/theme-specific-drupal-commerce-product-form), it does not have an accepted answer and it does not work, i think the problem is that form_id is incorrect, code does not even dpm($form), i've google arround looking for correct hook and form_id, but nothing helpfull came up, i use my_module_form_alter() because i use it to modify several forms, i stripped other forms code, this is my code:

```
 function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
          global $user;
          //$account = $user;
          $uuid = $user->uid;
    /*  check that user is NOT admin (No1) */
      if ($uuid !='1') {

           // FIRST ATTEMPT 
           if ($form_id == 'commerce_product_product_form') {
               //dsm($form);
               hide($form['commerce_price']);
               $form['field_my_field']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
            }

            // SECOND ATTEMPT
            if ($form_id == 'commerce-product-ui-product-form') {
                //dsm($form);
                hide($form['commerce_price']);
                $form['field_my_field']['#disabled'] = TRUE; 
             }
        }
```

comments on my code: inspecting code in mozzilla it says formd_id = 'commerce-product-ui-product-form' (second attempt in my code), but from a [very old commerce issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/1843302)  answered by Ryan Szrama he suggest to use 'commerce_product_product_form' instead (first attempt in my code), any help will be very appreciated. regards.